# Metrics not send to telegraf using python and statsd

Tags: python, prometheus, metrics, telegraf, statsd

I written a python code to create metrics and send them to telegraf and create graphs in grafana.
I use prometheus + telegraf + grafana stack. the problem is that there is no error in my python code and every thing seems to be ok but there are no metric saved in telegraf.

I implemented in docker

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  prometheus_data: {}
  grafana_data: {}

networks:
  grafana:
    name: grafana

services:

  prometheus:
    hostname: prometheus
    container_name: prometheus
    image: prom/prometheus
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus/
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles'
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    networks:
      - grafana

  grafana:
    hostname: grafana/grafana:10.0.1
    container_name: grafana
    image: grafana/grafana
    user: '472'
    restart: always
    environment:
      GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS: 'grafana-clock-panel,grafana-simple-json-datasource'
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
      - ./grafana/provisioning/:/etc/grafana/provisioning/
    env_file:
      - ./grafana/config.monitoring
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
    networks:
      - grafana

  telegraf:
    hostname: telegraf
    container_name: telegraf
    image: telegraf:1.28-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9100:9100
      - 8125:8125/udp
    volumes:
      - ./telegraf/telegraf.conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
    networks:
      - grafana
```

my telegraf.conf:

```
# Telegraf Configuration

[agent]
  interval = "10s"
  round_interval = true
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000
  flush_buffer_when_full = true
  collection_jitter = "0s"
  flush_interval = "10s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  precision = ""
  debug = true
  quiet = false
  hostname = ""
  omit_hostname = false

[[outputs.prometheus_client]]
  listen = "telegraf:9100"

[[inputs.statsd]]
  name_prefix = "local_statsd_"
  protocol = "udp"
  service_address = ":8125"
  metric_separator = "_"

[[inputs.cpu]]
  percpu = true
  totalcpu = true
  fielddrop = ["time_*"]

[[inputs.disk]]
  ignore_fs = ["tmpfs", "devtmpfs"]

[[inputs.diskio]]

[[inputs.kernel]]

[[inputs.mem]]

[[inputs.processes]]

[[inputs.swap]]

[[inputs.system]]

[[inputs.net]]
  # Specify specific interfaces if needed, e.g., interfaces = ["eth0"]

[[inputs.netstat]]

[[inputs.interrupts]]

[[inputs.linux_sysctl_fs]]
```

my python code ('docker' is my docker machine):

```
class StatDMetricProvider(BaseMetricProvider):

    def __init__(self, host='docker', port=8125, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.statsd = statsd.StatsClient(host, port, prefix="local_statsd_")

    def error_counter_metric(self, method, status_code, hot_wallet):
        metric_name = f'response_error_exceptions.method:{method}.status_code:{status_code}'
        self.statsd.incr(metric_name)
```